# Conflicting UIBarbuttonItem's tintcolor and image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar, tintcolor, uitoolbaritem

I have a `UIToolbar` in one of my VCs, it has 3 color buttons which changes the color of my drawing. Anyways I want to change the button's image when its selected. The images are shown below, the problem is apparently the button's "tintcolor" is messing with the original image.
If i set the "tintcolor" to red my active button looks like a bigger red circle, if its "clearcolor" it doesn't show. Any help would be much appreciated guys.

[image: Normal State]

[image: Selected State]

`UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red-selected"];`

`[button setImage:image];`

I even tried:

`UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"red-selected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];`

Comment: didnt understand your question

Comment: I have a UIBarbuttonItem which its normal image is the first one. When I set the image to the second one, it shows as a bigger red circle (without the border and the white part in between. It is because the tintcolor of the UIBarButton or something else, do you know something about it?

Comment: you set an image on the first and an image on the second but you arent saying nothing about these buttons..the image is the same in both case? you have a red circle in the second case, is an image or what?

Comment: The summary is when I set the second image i showed in my post, It doesnt show as it is, it shows as a complete red circle.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [btn setImage:@"red-selected.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

you can also do it in the interface builder - indicates a photo for selected mode.

pay attention the type of the photo- is it png?
try @"red-selected.png"/ @"red-selected.jpg"